# C++ error 'Undefined reference to Class<T>::Function' - Uso de templates

Tags: c++

Alguien podría ayudarme con este problema: estoy aprendiendo C++ y decidí crear un 'linked list' con clases, pero aparte también utilizo templates. Cuando compilo el programa me dice que la referencia a **'Linked_list< T >::Linked_list()'** es indefinida. Y esto pasa con todos los métodos de la clase.

Error:

```
C:\Users\Oskar\programacion\c++\data-structures\linked-list\main1.o main1.cpp:(.text+0x24e): undefined reference to `Linked_list<int>::~Linked_list()'
```

```
C:\Users\Oskar\programacion\c++\data-structures\linked-list\main1.o main1.cpp:(.text+0x1f3): undefined reference to `Node<int>::get_next() const'
```

Los siguientes errores me los marca para todos los métodos de las dos clases.

Tambien utilizo una clase **'Node'** para enlazar los datos y me marca el mismo error que el de **'Linked_list'**.

No se si este implementando de manera correcta los templates, así que agradecería que me corrigieran y me ayudaran con este problema, gracias.

linked_list.h

```cpp
#ifndef LINKED_LIST_H
#define LINKED_LIST_H

#include "node.h"

template <class T>
class Linked_list {
    private:
        Node<T> *root;
    public:
        Linked_list();
        ~Linked_list();
        Node<T> * get(int);
        Node<T> * first();
        void add(T);
        int size();
        bool is_empty();
};

#endif
```

linked_list.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "linked_list.h"
#include "node.h"
#include "helpers.h"

template <class T>
Linked_list<T>::Linked_list() {
    root = NULL;
}

template <class T>
Linked_list<T>::~Linked_list() {
    delete root;
}

template <class T>
Node<T> * Linked_list<T>::get(int index) {
    if(is_empty()) return NULL;

    return travel_for_get(0,index,root);
}

template <class T>
Node<T> * Linked_list<T>::first() {
    return root;
}

template <class T>
void Linked_list<T>::add(T value) {
    if(is_empty()) {
        root = new Node<T>(value);
    } else {
        travel_list(root, value);
    }
}

template <class T>
int Linked_list<T>::size() {
    if(is_empty()) return 0;

    return travel_for_size(1, root->get_next());
}

template <class T>
bool Linked_list<T>::is_empty() {
    if(root == NULL) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

template <class T>
class Node {
    private:
        T value;
        Node<T> *next;
    public:
        Node(T);
        void set_value(T);
        T get_value() const;
        void set_next(Node<T> *);
        Node<T> * get_next() const;
};

#endif
```

node.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"

template <class T>
Node<T>::Node(T value) {
    next = NULL;
    this->value = value;
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::set_value(T value) {
    this->value = value;
}

template <class T>
T Node<T>::get_value() const {
    return this->value;
}

template <class T>
Node<T> * Node<T>::get_next() const {
    return this->next;
}

template <class T>
void Node<T>::set_next(Node * next) {
    this->next = next;
}
```

helpers.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "node.h"

template <typename T>
void travel_list(Node <T> *, T);
template <typename T>
Node <T> * travel_for_get(int, int, Node <T> *);
template <typename T>
int travel_for_size(int, Node <T> *);

template <typename T>
void travel_list(Node <T> * node, T value) {
    if(node->get_next() == NULL) {
        node->set_next(new Node<T>(value));
    } else {
        travel_list(node->get_next(), value);
    }
}

template <typename T>
Node <T> * travel_for_get(int curr_index, int index, Node <T> *curr_node) {
    if(curr_index == index) return curr_node;

    return travel_for_get(curr_index+1, index, curr_node->get_next());
}

template <typename T>
int travel_for_size(int curr_size, Node <T> * curr_node) {

    if(curr_node == NULL) return curr_size;

    return travel_for_size(curr_size+1, curr_node->get_next());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar, déjame darte la bienvenida a la página y felicitarte por ser de las pocas personas que desarrolla una lista y lo hace adecuadamente.

---

Aún haciendo las cosas de manera adecuada, te has topado con un error común en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b): Las plantillas no se pueden separar en declaración y definición si la definición está en un archivo que no se incluye.

Las plantillas C++ pueden ser declaradas, definidas o instanciadas:

- **Declaración**: Se indica que la plantilla existe sin detallar cómo es; el nombre de la plantilla podrá usarse siempre que no provoque la creación de una instancia. En otras palabras, nos describe la plantilla sin entrar en detalles:

  [image]
- **Definición**: Se describe la plantilla al detalle, cuenta como declaración si no había declaración previa, puede instanciarse la plantilla sin limitaciones. Es decir, nos detalla la plantilla al completo:

  [image]
- **Instanciación**: Cuando se indican (o se deducen) los parámetros de la plantilla. En otras palabras, crea lo que corresponda con las características indicadas:

  [image]

---

Si declaramos la plantilla en un archivo de cabecera (`hpp`) y la definimos en un archivo de código (`cpp`), cuando se instancie la plantilla el compilador no encontrará la definición (excepto para especializaciones de plantilla) y el código no podrá ser compilado.

[image]

---

Para evitar este problema, tanto la declaración como la definición deben ser visibles en el punto de instanciación de la plantilla, ya sea en el mismo archivo como en otro archivo que también se incluya (`#include`).

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedo muy claro con tu explicación.